# DispatcherOperation.Abort() sometimes slow?

Tags: wpf, dispatcher

I have a [DispatcherOperation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that is sometimes aborted. The [Abort](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcheroperation.abort%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method usually returns in no time, but sometimes it takes over 50 ms. I can see that it is in status `Pending` when this happens.

**What causes the `Abort` function to delay randomly but not always?**

Comment: -1 Provide more information, snippet of your code to replicate the problem would helpful.

Comment: This is a question about the inner workings of a `.NET` provided class. I have looked through the `DispatcherOperation.cs` source, trying to figure out what could cause this. More information than that is not available. A sample would not help as there is nothing fancy in my code, except frequent calls to `BeginInvoke()` and `Abort()`. The latter showing an *undocumented* behavior.

Comment: I am sorry, didn't understand the question first time. I have edited it.

Comment: What version of the framework do you target? Also, do you handle `DispatcherHooks.OperationAborted` or `DispatcherOperation.Aborted` events anywhere?

Comment: `.NET 4.5.1`. No such events handled. The only thing I can think of is a race condition where the `Abort` is called at the same time as the operation is started.